# how to restart the JVM?

Tags: java

is there any possibility of unloading all the java class from the JVM or restart the JVM.

i have called System.exit(0) in my application when certain condition is met, all i want is restart the application that is start from main method onwards

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Process` to start a new VM

Answer (score 0):

check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi